# My char device can't open

Tags: c, linux, char, device, linux-device-driver

I have a problem which have been confusing me for a week. I wish someone can help me.
I wrote a simple char device module, `insmod` it to kernel and `mknod` a char file under `/dev`. I can see a it after I `insmod` it by `cat /proc/devices`. But there is an error when I open this char device file.

My char device code is:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/mm.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <asm/io.h>
#include <asm/system.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#define CALL_DEV_NAME  "mn2"
#define CALL_DEV_MAJOR 230
struct cdev cdev;
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

int call_open(struct inode *inode,struct file *filp){
    int num=MINOR(inode->i_rdev);
    printk("call open minor is:%d \n",num);
    return 0;
}


static struct file_operations call_fops={
    .owner=THIS_MODULE,
    .open=call_open,
};

int call_init(void){
    int result;
    printk("call call_init \n");
    result=register_chrdev_region(MKDEV(CALL_DEV_MAJOR,0),
        1,CALL_DEV_NAME);
    if(result<0){
        printk("registerfail \n");
        return result;
    }
    cdev_init(&cdev,&call_fops);
    cdev.ops=&call_fops;
    cdev.owner=THIS_MODULE;
    cdev_add(&cdev,MKDEV(CALL_DEV_MAJOR,0),1);
    return 0;
}

void call_exit(void){
    printk("call call_exit \n");
    unregister_chrdev(CALL_DEV_MAJOR,CALL_DEV_NAME);
}

module_init(call_init);
module_exit(call_exit);
```

the test code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fd;
    fd=fopen("/dev/mn2","r+");

    if(fd==NULL)
    printf("fail\n");
    }
```

My Makefile is :

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
obj-m := mn2.o
else
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    rm -f *.ko *.o *.mod.o *.mod.c *.symvers *.order
endif
```

The command I use is:

```
make
insmod mn2.ko
```

then I can see `mn2` in `/proc/devices`

```
mknod mn2 c 230 0
```

and there are also a file as `mn2` under `/dev`

But after I compile the test.c by `gcc test.c -o test` and run the  test, I always get a `fail` world.

Can you help me spot my error?

Comment: Use `perror` rather than your printf so that you at least get the actual error message. (And try not to mess up your own post's formatting.)

Comment: Was `call_open`'s `printk` printed?

Comment: yes,i have find the reason,which lack of 'r+' authority.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

`fprintf(stderr, "fopen() failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));`

include a file `<errno.h>`.
It will give you details about error. I think its authority problem. Try to run your user-space binary with sudo.